# CSS to swap div from desktop to mobile

Tags: css, media-queries

I have two divs for desktop and mobile, but the div for mobile doesn't show when I use the Inspect tool to pick different sizes for mobile.

```css
.outdoor { 
  display:block; 
}

.outdoor-m { 
  display:none; 
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .outdoor { 
    display:none!important; 
  }
 
  .outdoor-m { 
    display:block!important; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outdoor">
  <img src="outdoor.jpg">
</div>

<div class="outdoor-m">
  <img src="outdoor-600.jpg">
</div>
```

Really appreciate your help

Comment: It's working fine and visible in inspect dev tool. what's the problem here ?

Comment: Are you using a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) ?Without it, the mobile browser would assume that the page is not optimized for mobile and would emulate a wider viewport.

Comment: Thanks so much. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> is the key!  After I added it, now it's working! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

The following example shows the `<div>` element with the `.outdoor` class style applied on desktop and tablet devices; this `<div>` element is not displayed on mobile devices. The `<div>` element with the `.outdoor-m` class style is displayed on mobile devices; this `<div>` element is not displayed on desktop and tablet devices. For mobile compatible devices, the maximum screen width should be `768px` to write a media query. *To test the application, you can enlarge or reduce the width of the page in the full-screen preview.*

```css
.outdoor{
  display: block; 
}

.outdoor-m { 
  display: none; 
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .outdoor { 
    display: none !important; 
  }
  
  .outdoor-m { 
    display: block !important; 
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="outdoor">Active: Desktop</h1>
<h1 class="outdoor-m">Active: Mobile</h1>

<!-- This <div> is displayed on desktop devices and tablets. -->
<div class="outdoor">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
</div>

<!-- On mobile devices this <div> is displayed. -->
<div class="outdoor-m">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
</div>
```

Comment: What was the problem? that `!important` was stuck to `none` and `block`?